# When a program exits and unloads my .dll, my worker threads terminate before I can free their memory

Tags: multithreading, memory-leaks, exit

I have a .dll that is statically linked to the MFC.  During normal use of the .dll, it will create a worker thread using `AfxBeginThread`.  Inside the function for that thread I create two arrays:

```
CByteArray ReadBuffer;
ReadBuffer.SetSize(92);
CByteArray PacketBuffer;
PacketBuffer.SetSize(46);
```

Those buffers will change size (typically to much larger) during the program execution.  The problem is, when the program exits, the function for the thread seems to terminate without ever getting a chance to free the memory allocated by those arrays. I have an `ExitInstance()` in the .dll overloaded to do other clean up, but the time it is reached I already get the messages:

```
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x2208) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1e34) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1ff8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1fc0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

These show the thread is being terminated in the middle of execution and doesn't seem to give it time to call any destructors or do any cleanup.

I tried to create my own `CWinThread` object with an overloaded `ExitInstance()` function, but again those threads exit before that function is called.

After the .dlls close function is called and the memory cleaned up, I get this:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\array_b.cpp(110) : {258} normal block at 0x023686E8, 2048 bytes long.
Data: <                > C6 F9 1D C0 E2 0C 00 00 00 00 AA 00 C0 11 E0 11 
f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\array_b.cpp(110) : {201} normal block at 0x02366F00, 64 bytes long.
Data: <b           @   > 62 F9 1D C0 81 09 00 00 00 00 7F 00 40 11 E0 10 
Object dump complete.
```

Showing leaks caused by the `ReadBuffer` and `PacketBuffer` from above.  I can't find a way to properly close the threads & clean up their memory before the program exits.  I have a way to gracefully terminate the threads that I could use, but I can't find a spot to execute it before the program terminates.

I am not sure that this is even a big issue, since the program is terminating, but always thought .dlls should clean up all of their own memory just to be safe.

Comment: Look, it's like this: if it's not causing an issue, don't bother about it.  The OS can clean up upon process temination. 'I am not sure that this is even a big issue, since the program is terminating' - it isn't, unless you make it so.

Comment: 'Detected memory leaks!' - ignore immediate, unless the 'leaks' increase in size/quantity with app run-time.